# How to import only one math symbol from other package like stix

Tags: math-fonts, import, stix, fourier

I am using fouriernc package. The font is beautiful but the math symbol \in and \notin is ugly. How can I use default \in and \notin symbols or the symbols provided by stix package but the whole document, text and math work with fouriernc?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\( 0 \notin \mathbb{N} \text{ but } 0 \in \mathbb{W} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: output]